# Svg charting library

Tags: javascript, svg, charts

Do you know if there's any SVG + js charting library out there similar to http://www.amcharts.com/ (Flash). I need to provide nice looking interactive chart functionality in a browser that does not support Flash but supports SVG.

Answer (score 75):

Depending on licensing requirements and features you have a few options. SVG is not supported from IE 6 to IE8 so you may find some libraries using canvas to run on IE, and others using VML to run on IE.

- [**Plotkit**](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/) is a mixed SVG+Canvas library, latest version is a bit outdated (0.9.1 released in 29 August 2006) BSD licensed.
- [**Elycharts**](http://elycharts.com) is an SVG+VML library (using RaphaelJS under the hood) with a good feature set, interactivity and cool animations. (last version 2.1.3 from December 2010) Mit licensed.
- [**g.raphael**](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) is an SVG+VML library (using RaphaelJS, from the same author of RaphaelJS). It is very good for infographics, less good for classical charts. (last version 0.4.1 from 2009) Mit Licensed.
- [**Grafico**](http://grafico.kilianvalkhof.com/) is again an SVG+VML library (again RaphaelJS based). It has much more chart types than gRaphael or Elycharts but less options/configurability than Elycharts. MIT licensed.
- [**Google Chart Tools**](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) provides SVG+VML based charts. It's free to use but I didn't find the complete licensing terms. It also provides an editor (even if it is not easy to find on their site)
- [**D3.js**](http://d3js.org/) Is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data. D3 helps you bring data to life using HTML, SVG and CSS.

You also have some commercial option:

- [**ZingChart**](http://www.zingchart.com/) - This is the only library allowing SVG, VML, canvas and flash in order to support every device out there. It is expensive but very complete.
- [**HighCharts**](http://www.highcharts.com/) - A very complete SVG+VML library having a very good documentation and a very complete feature set. It has a free for personal use license but it shows a very "strict" interpretation of personal and your own blog may not be considered "personal", that's why I show it under "commercial options".

Comment: I forgot to write about "Ico", another SVG+VML (Raphael) library. You can find it on github because its site is not working: https:// github.com/uiteoi/ico

Comment: Another commercial option: SmartClient and SmartGWT support SVG+Canvas+VML charts from IE6 up, and also support mobile (Android/iOS).  See http://blog.isomorphic.com/html5-charts-with-mobile-support/

Comment: Don't forget about the original posted one - http://www.amcharts.com/ is no longer just flash.  They have javascript & flash charts, and you can use it for free if you want the link.  It looks really nice to me.

Comment: Google Charts are on the Apache License (or at least examples are as stated on the bottom of the gallery page).

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to be a little more specific about the features that you need, but you might want to look at [PlotKit](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/).

Answer (score 2):

Now **amCharts** provides **SVG charts** and still generate flash charts for old browsers that doesn't support **SVG**.

**amCharts** support all modern browsers including modern versions of `Firefox`, `Chrome`, `Safari`, `Opera` and `Internet Explorer`. It also runs on mobile devices powered by `iOS` (`iPad`, `iPhone`, `iPod Touch`) and `Android Honeycomb`.

Good stuff, huh?
http://www.amcharts.com/

Comment: It seem to fallback to VML now.

Answer (score 2):

[D3](http://d3js.org/) is a quite good open-source charting library which uses SVG.

Answer (score 1):

The google visualization API has some SVG charts you can use http://code.google.com/apis/visualization
While this is not an avg library, it is a charting one.

Comment: Visualizations does have some limitations that you should be careful about like the fact that you need a connection to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com)? It renders charts in HTML5 Canvas, SVG and Flash (and VML for old IE fallback).

I'm on the team. You can reach our team at support[at]zingchart.com with any questions, or mention/follow us at http://twitter.com/zingchart.

-Andrew

Answer (score 0):

[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) could also be useful - check out gRaphaël—Charting Plugin - it has really impressive examples.