# Graphing Library for 50k points? PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jqplot, graphing, large-data

After a lot of searching on SO, I couldn't find an answer to my specific use-case.

I've been using jQplot for a PHP/Javascript page that plots 100-200 different series with up to 50 points each. The problem is, that it is drawing each individual series as its own canvas layer, and eats up a TON of memory in the browser.

I want to get to the point of drawing 2000 series of 30-50 points each, and can deal without a lot of the interactive features that a lot of javascript graphing libraries present.

Is there a free (public license) graphing library out there that produces static images? Would such libraries take a long time to render such an image?

I do like the way jqplot looks, but I can't really expand my graph beyond 400x400 px without it taking a huge amount of RAM.

Comment: Dunno what you need but have you taken a look at Flot.js???

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793808/svg-charting-library

Comment: Is a set of SVG charts going to render that many points effectively?

Comment: [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) might be of interest.

Comment: google charts does not produce static images.  I would imagine it'd use a lot of memory also.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the PHP class oriented framework http://pchart.sourceforge.net/ ?