# Google-like Stock Chart / Line Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, charts, angular-material

I'm looking for a specific style of Javascript or SVG chart library that resembles a [Google Chart (example)](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=Alphabet+stock+ticker)

[image: Google search: "NASDAQ: GOOG" shows a stock chart like this.]

I have searched for some time but can't find anything that closely resembles this style, and I was curious if anyone could point me in the right direction to achieve a similar end result.

I have looked in to the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) and tried making a [Line Chart in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaggedsoftware/oek6qLm9/) but can't seem to replicate that style of design. Any advice?

```
See Example Image
```

Javascript, SVG, and AngularJS are all acceptable for the bounty reward. Bonus points for SVG.

Comment: In what way isn't the chart in your jsfiddle matching the chart above? It looks very close to me (which i suppose isn't a surprise, given they're both google charts). If you want dates in the x axis you just have to supply the right axis type and objects in the data, see the update at:     https://jsfiddle.net/wbufx12p/1/

Comment: Here is a few resources that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793808/svg-charting-library ... http://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for the advice @mgraham and LGSon - here is where I'm at so far: https://jsfiddle.net/jaggedsoftware/tr5dsgwL/

Comment: You're either asking for a library recommendation (off topic), or asking someone to code and style a chart for you (too broad; off topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: First Screenshot]

This is the closest I've managed to get, and I think I did a pretty good job given the requirements.

If you'd like the tooltip to always show when you're hovering over the chart [(Example: Google Trends)](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=gravitational%20waves%2Cstackoverflow) this can be accomplished with the `focusTarget` option [(Example JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/jaggedsoftware/oek6qLm9/) which currently only works with Classic Google charts and not the new material charts.

```js
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2015, 9, 28), 6],
    [new Date(2015, 9, 29), 10],
    [new Date(2015, 9, 30), 19],
    [new Date(2015, 10, 0), 14],
    [new Date(2015, 10, 1), 16],

  ]);

  var options = {
    colors: ["#4184F3"],
    lineWidth: 3,
    legend: {
      position: "none"
    },
    hAxis: {
      pointSize: 2,
      format: 'MMM d',
      title: '',
      titlePosition: 'none'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```css
#chart_div svg g circle {
  stroke: #4184F3 !important;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  r: 5;
  fill: #4184F3 !important;
  filter: none !important;
}
#chart_div svg g circle:hover {
  r: 8
}
#chart_div svg g path {
  stroke-width: 4 !important;
  stroke: #4184F3 !important;
  stroke-linejoin: bevel;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  filter: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: See thread: Google-visualization-api: [Request for focusTarget to work on material charts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/Ol2yVy6mrVE)

Comment: please can you see my question maybe you have an idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256487/i-want-to-change-the-chart-for-each-city-or-subcity-selected

Comment: I recommend http://metricsgraphicsjs.org/examples.htm as well